# Maxwell- Boltzmann's law of distribution of speeds

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, kinetic-theory

I am a JEE Aspirant and preparing for this competitive exam . I saw this problem

[image]

For this Problem , all options given are correct . I am able to figure out Option A ,  but I cannot figure out other option using formula for rms velocity , average velocity. could you please tell what am I missing . Thanks in advance .

Comment: *All options given are correct.* Are you sure? I’m skeptical that this is true.

Comment: @ Smith_G Yes all options are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see from the graph it seems that
$$\frac{dN}{dv} = \frac{a}{v_0}v$$
and so the average value of $v$ should be
$$v_{avg} = \frac{1}{N} \int_0^{v_0}{v dN}$$
$$ = \frac{a}{Nv_0} \int_0^{v_0}{v^2dv}$$
which comes out to be $\frac{2}{3}v_0$ after using the answer to part a and simplifying. So either the answer is wrong or I missed a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ somewhere. But this is how you should approach the problem. For part c, $v_{rms}$ is the square root of the average value of $v^2$ which is
$$(v^2)_{avg} = \frac{1}{N} \int_0^{v_0}{v^2 dN}$$
For part d try finding $N(v)$ first by integrating $\frac{dN}{dv}$. Really, this is more of a calculus problem than a physics problem.